Multiple color border angle on 45 degrees in CSS
The first image is what i'm trying to achieve, the second is what i've managed so far.
I'm trying to achieve this alert message using CSS only without importing image
1
2
I'm stuck with the top border with alternating colors on a 45 degree angle. I can't figure out how to rotate the angle by 45 degrees.
This is what I have so far.
<style>
.alert {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-right: 350px;
  
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px 15px 15px 15px silver;
}

.button {
 
  padding: 5px 8px 5px 20px;
 
  line-height: 1.2;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
 
}

.boxborder-me {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px yellow;
  outline: dashed 5px brown;
  height: 100px;
}

.alert h3 {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 16px;
 }
.checkmark {
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: green;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
.warning {
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: orange;
      font-size: 48px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
   
.warn,
.warn::before,
.warn::after
{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.warn {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: transparent;
}

.warn.warning {
  display: inline-block;

  top: 0.225em;

  width: 1.15em;
  height: 1.15em;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0.425em;
}

.warn.warning::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  top: -0.08em;
  left: 0.0em;
  position: absolute;
  border: transparent 0.6em solid;
  border-bottom-color: #F5B041;
  border-bottom-width: 1em;
  border-top-width: 0;
  
}

.warn.warning::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Garamond";
  content: "!";
  font-size: 0.65em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0;
  valign: top;
}

.alert-message {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 0;
}
.alert {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 30px;

}
        
        .topborder{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px yellow;
  outline: dashed 6px brown;  
  padding: 0px;
}

</style>

<body style="background-color: #EEE">
        <div class="alert">
            <div>
                <div class="topborder"/>
            </div>
            <table valign="top">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 0 10px 0 0px">
                        <div>
                            <span class="warn warning"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Alert</h3>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 0 7px 0 0px"/>
                    <td>
                        <div class="alert-message">
                            <span>Please input details to proceed.</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 0 7px 0 0px"/>
                    <td>
                        <div style="text-align:right">
                            <label>
                                <a class="button" href="goBack">
                                    <span class="checkmark">&#10003;</span>
                            OK</a>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

